# Is there a way to convert a Nurbs curve to Bezier?

Tags: bezier-curves

Apparently paths are the easiest way to make a spiral. But I'm using a spiral for a particle curve guide and Path doesn't work with Curve Guide. So I'm just wondering if it's possible to turn the curve from Path to like the thing that the Bezier is like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under *Edit Mode* in the *Tools* tab of the *Tool Shelf* there is a button labeled *Set Spline Type* to switch between several curve types like *Poly*, *Bezier* or *NURBS*.

[image]

Under 2.8+ this can be set from the *3D View header menu > Curve > Set Spline Type*.

[image]

Spline type is stored as a per-curve spline property. A spline is any connected sequence of vertex in *Edit Mode* within a single curve object, that means each  different spline within a curve can have its own independent type.